# MailSendException: Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException

Tags: java, spring, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I try to send an email using javaMail, spring-boot and yahoo. I got this SMTPSendFailedException and I don't know why.

Here a part of the exception:

```
ErrorPageFilter: Forwarding to error page from request [/registration] due to exception [Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 501 Syntax error in arguments
;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 Syntax error in arguments
]
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 501 Syntax error in arguments
;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 Syntax error in arguments
; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 501 Syntax error in arguments
;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 Syntax error in arguments

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2203)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1694)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1194)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:433)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:307)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:296)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 Syntax error in arguments

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1703)
    ... 102 more
[2015-10-27 22:11:14.252] boot - 8407 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-8] --- EndpointHandlerMapping: Looking up handler method for path /error
[2015-10-27 22:11:14.257] boot - 8407 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-8] --- EndpointHandlerMapping: Did not find handler method for [/error]
```

The Email config properties, I use yahoo as host:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.mail.yahoo.com
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.username=*****@yahoo.com
spring.mail.password=*****
spring.mail.default-encoding=UTF-8
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable=true
```

The part of the implementation which send the email;

```
@Autowired
JavaMailSender javaMailSender;


    String recipientAddress = XXXX.getUser().getEmail();
    String subject = "Bienvenue chez AAAA";
    String message = "huhuu";
    SimpleMailMessage email = new SimpleMailMessage();
    email.setTo(recipientAddress);
    email.setSubject(subject);
    email.setText(message + "\n");
    javaMailSender.send(email);
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What version of JavaMail are you using?  Can you capture the [debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug)?  The mail server is complaining about the SMTP MAIL FROM command, which probably means the From address of your message isn't set correctly.  Since you don't seem to be setting it explicitly, perhaps SimpleMailMessage is choosing a default that's bad?  Setting it explicitly to a legal value will probably solve the problem.